# Open VPN with win XP and wireless card

Tags: windows-xp, openvpn, 802.1

I'm trying to run an OpenVPN VPN  on an XP box. It works fine when I have a physical connection plugged in to the wired Ethernet port. However, when I try to run it with the wireless card as the primary interface I get a new connection created in my control panel that refuses to connect. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: How is the wireless connection routed to your VPN target and does that differ significantly from the wired connection that works.

Comment: I can't tell. When I run open vpn it creates a new connection that is broken and won't connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using tcp instead of udp. A friend of mine got some trouble with wireless connection to ovpn. Connection breaks etc.
UDP is a little bit faster than tcp in OVPN, but firstly try to get a clean and long time lasting connection.

You need the `proto tcp-server` option to enable this on server side and `proto tcp` on client side.

Secondly make sure to use the same interface type on both end. I use the tap on both machines.

Comment: I'll give this a try